# How to convert between timezones in Go?

Tags: go, timezone

For example `time.Now()` has a timezone of UTC.

```
utcNow := time.Now()
fmt.Println(utcNow)
```

Outputs

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

How do I convert this time to Japan Standard time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're running that in the Go playground, which is why the time is automatically set to UTC (it's also always set to November 2009 when a program is launched).

If you run `time.Now()` on your own machine, it should pick up the local region. Alternatively, if you want to force the time to be in a specific timezone, you can use a time.Location object along with the time.Time.In function.

```
l, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Tokyo") // Look up a location by it's IANA name.
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // You can handle this gracefully.
}
fmt.Println(utcNow.In(l))
```

Note that it's still showing the same moment in time, but now with JST's offset.

For more information, look at the go documentation for the time package. http://golang.org/pkg/time

Comment: Thanks! So simple. I missed that in the docs 

Comment: Link to solution in Go playground http://play.golang.org/p/mlurw6CyaK

Comment: How do you print the time in another timezone. I.e show a server generated time to the user in their timezone